# float navigation buttons left and right with dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float the two elements, below is what I've got:

html

```
<div id="navBar">
<div class="navBarStyles">
    <ul class="mainNavBar">
        <li><div class="menu-icon iconStyles">z</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navBarInfo">
        <li><div class="i-icon iconStyles">u</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div style="clear: both"> </div>
</div>
```

css

```
@media only screen
        and (max-width : 500px) {
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                text-align: center;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #navBar .menu-icon{
                padding-left: 18px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul li{
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul a{
                color: #666666;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
                display: none;  
            }

            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul{
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                text-align: center;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #navBar .i-icon{
                width: 20px;
                padding-left: 18px;
            }
            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul li{
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul a{
                color: #666666;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul{
                display: none;  
            }
        }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cae6/1/)

I need to float the `i` button to the right of `z`, I tried to float the `z` to left and `i` to right they do line up horizontally but the ul list under the buttons doesn't take full width. Becomes something like this:

[jsFiddle-2](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cae6/2/)

That is what needs to be solved.

Below are the screen shots the results I need:

[image: when z is clicked]
[image: when u is clicked]

so when I click the `z` button, the u should not move from its place. this can be done with `position: absolute;` but with that approach the button won't move if the window is resized.

Comment: are you just trying to float the two menus?

Comment: just the buttons let me add a screen shot for better understanding.

Comment: So basically you want **z** and **u** to stand still and toggle their inner **li**'s when you click a link?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by giving `position: absolute` to the left (z) element, floating the right (u) one, and reversing the order of the markup. For now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ul's to inline blocks and then floating them. Also you can use absolute postioning to keep the icons in place.

## <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cae6/5/)</kbd>

css:

```
 ul { display: inline-block;}
ul li {display: inline-block;}
.left {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}
.menu-icon {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin: -13px;
z-index: 999;
}
#navBar{
    font-family: "opensans-semibold";
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0088FF; /*0088FF*/
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    margin-top:50px;
}

#navBar li{
    line-height: 48px;
}

.navBarStyles li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
@media only screen
        and (max-width : 500px) {
           #navBar .mainNavBar{
               float: left;
           } 
        
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                text-align: center;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #navBar .menu-icon{
                padding-left: 18px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul li{
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul a{
                color: #666666;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
                display: none;  
            }
                        
            #navBar .navBarInfo{
                float: right;
            }
            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul{
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                text-align: center;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #navBar .i-icon{
                width: 20px;
                padding-left: 18px;
            }
            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul li{
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul a{
                color: #666666;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #navBar .navBarInfo li ul{
                display: none;  
            }
        }
```

Comment: but when I click on `z` it still move the `u` below, why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify agconti's answer, you would just need to add:

```
ul { display: inline-block; float:left; }
```

Since all `ul` elements would bump up against each other, so if you added another `ul` it would sit to the right of `z`, depending on the order you add it in your HTML.

In case you want to spread the `ul` and `li` across horizontally, you would need to do something like:

```
ul, li { display: inline-block; float:left; }
```

and remove these ul's from your html, like so:

```
<div id="navBar">
<div class="navBarStyles">
    <ul class="mainNavBar">
        <li><div class="menu-icon iconStyles">z</div>
            <!-- remove this <ul> -->
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <!-- remove this </ul> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navBarInfo">
        <li><div class="i-icon iconStyles">u</div>
            <!-- remove this <ul> -->
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <!-- remove this </ul> -->
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div style="clear: both"> </div>
</div>
```

And you'll get all your buttons in a straight line